# How to trigger events in Javascript based on mouse click location parameters?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, canvas

I am trying to create a drawing app with HTML canvas and javascript. But I would like images to be shown based on where the user draws on the canvas. For example if the user draws in the area above the head, a picture of a hat is shown.

My solution so far has been a div which is placed where I want the parameters to be that hides on mouseclick and after a delay (hopefully long enough for user to finish drawing) shows a image in another div.

```css
    $(document).ready(function(){

          $(".hat").click(function(){
            $("#hathide").delay( 3000 ).fadeIn( 200 );
          });
        });

        $(document).ready(function(){

          $(".hat").click(function(){
            $(".hat").hide(0);
          });
      
        
        });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<main class="main-content">
        <div class="left">
            <div class="grid-container">
                <div><img id="hathide" src="img/hat.gif" style="display:none"></div> 
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="right">
            <div class="hat">draw a hat</div>
            <div class="drawingcanvas"><div>
            <div class="image-container">
                <img src="img/person.jpg">
            </div>
    </div>
```

This doesn't suit my needs because this means the user needs to first click on the div to hide it and then draw on the canvas. I would like it so that the user draws directly on the canvas and for javascript to detect whether the drawing was done within the certain parameters to trigger the image to show.

I've tried to style the div with pointer-events:none; so the user can directly draw on the canvas but that meant the div wouldn't be targetable and wouldn't hide.

Additionally, this method doesn't truly listen for the user's input it just seems like it does. I would want it so an event is called when the user mouse is pressed within the parameters and the mouse is released. Ideally, it would be independent of the javascript code used for drawing so there would be no interference?

I am not too familiar with JS or jQuery enough to write my own syntax but I would think something along the lines of

```
 $canvas.mouseup(
If  100 < page.x < 400, and 100 < page.y < 400: then show div;
Else none
)
```

Sorry, that is not real code.

I've been looking around this website and trying to find alternative solutions but I can't seem to figure it out on my own.

Any help and solutions would be greatly appreciated. It doesn't necessarily have to be Javascript/jQuery. Thank you!

Comment: A solution to waiting for a period of time after they have finished is using a higher order "debounce" method. Take a look at lodash debounce. You could delay running the function that places the object until some time after they have finished drawing.

Answer (score 0):

The logic to determine weather you are in a certain area of the canvas or not is fairly simple. The method `getMousePos()` returns the x and y position of the mouse, relative to the top left corner of the target element of the given Event.

```js
/**
* Get the mouse position relative to the top left corner 
* of the target element of the given event
*/
function getMousePos( e ) {
    let $el = $(e.target);
    let elX = e.pageX - $el.offset().left;
  let elY = e.pageY - $el.offset().top;
  return {
    x: elX, 
    y: elY
  };
}

function inTarget( mousePos ) {
  // consider using a map to use multiple target areas
  return mousePos.x > 100 && mousePos.x < 200 && mousePos.y > 100 && mousePos.y < 200
}

function doSomething() {
  $('#hat').show();
}

function doSomethingElse() {
  $('#hat').hide();
}

$('canvas').on('mousedown', function() {
  // enable draw mode
  $(this).data('drawMode', true);
});

$('body').on('mouseup', function() {
  $('canvas').data('drawMode', false);
})

$('canvas').on('mousemove', function( e ) {
  if(!$(this).data('drawMode')) {
    return;
  }
  let mousePos = getMousePos( e );
  if( inTarget( mousePos ) ) {
    doSomething();
  }else{
    doSomethingElse();
  }
});
```

```css
canvas {
  border: 1px solid #CECECE;
  background-color: #F1F1F1;
}
#hat {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: red;
  top: 100px;
  left: 100px;
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="hat"></div>
<canvas width="300" height="300">
</canvas>
<br/>
<span>Click and move the mouse to draw</span>
```